# How to add iframe to vbulletin?

Tags: iframe, embed, vbulletin

I want users to be able to embed to iframe videos, no matter from which site. Currently when you do that, the system seems to strip the iframe. I am wondering how to enable posting iframe. I also I'd like to know whether there are any risks in embeding iframes that justified limiting the ability to certain user groups. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See if it helps: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/18640-iframe-in-bbcode

Comment: It is for VB 2. I'm on VB 4.2. Unfortuanately, could not make sense of it.